# Get other athletes in a group activity?

Tags: strava

I want to figure out which people I run with the most from Strava.

More concretely:

I want to get a list of all of `Athlete` **A's** activities, but I also want to know for each activity which other `Athlete`s were involved.

e.g.
Is it possible with the current Strava API to get a list of other `Athletes` involved in each activity?

I know there is an `athlete_count` in `DetailedActivity` and `SummaryActivity` but that doesn't give me a unique identifier to differientiate different people.